# Laggy movement with canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hey guys not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've played a few HTML5 games and they've seem to suffer from a different issue.  The drawing lags behind the movement and it looks weird.  This doesn't seem to be the case here.

In my game the drawing seems fine, but it lags like every second as he moves.(movement is arrow keys).  It does it without arrow keys also, if I set him up to move automatically, so I don't think it's a key detection issue.

It's almost as if the garbage collector is running every second.  I don't think I'm spewing out that many objects though.

I'm using Chrome 21 (MacOSX) and also Firefox 14.

http://tempdrew.dreamhosters.com/spine/

Here is the js fiddle with relevant code.

http://jsfiddle.net/ju3ag/

This is fine on chrome canary.  I don't know if it's just because the javascript is so much faster in canary then standard chrome.  It's terrible in latest Firefox.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm updating movement based on time.  If I take that out though it's still bad.

I'm just wondering if anything will stand out to anyone.  Thanks for any help.

```
    sg = Class.extend({


});

sg.entities = [];
sg.buttonStates = [];

sg.createEntity = function (entity) {    
    this.entities.push(entity);    
};


window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function (callback, element) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };

})();


(function defineUtil() {

    sg.util = {};

    sg.util.getRandomInt = function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };

    sg.util.getRandomNumber = function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    };

})();


/*************************/
(function createEntity() {

    var Entity = Class.extend({

        init: function (x, y) {

            this.name = 'Entity';
            this.health = 100;

            this.pos = {
                x: x,
                y: y
            };

            this.vel = {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            };

            this.accel = {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            }

            console.log(this.name + ' created ' + x + ' ' + y);
        },

        update: function (elapsed) {

        },

        draw: function (ctx) {

        }

    });

    sg.Entity = Entity;

})();





/************************/

// -- player.js
(function createPlayer() {

    var Player = sg.Entity.extend({

        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        moveLeft: false,
        moveRight: false,
        speed : 5,

        init: function (x, y) {

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.name = 'Player';
        },

        draw: function (ctx) {

            var x = this.x,
                y = this.y;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(x, y, 40, 50);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.lineWidth = .5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)';
            ctx.fillRect(x + 25, y + 15, 5, 5);
        },

        update: function (elapsed) {
            var distance = (60 / 1000) * elapsed;
            if (this.moveLeft) {
                this.x += this.speed * distance;
            } else if (this.moveRight) {
                this.x -= this.speed * distance;
            }
        },

        keyDown: function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode === 39) {
                this.moveLeft = true;
            } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
                this.moveRight = true;
            } else {
                this.moveLeft = false;
                this.moveRight = false;
            }
        },

        keyUp: function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode === 39) {
                this.moveLeft = false;
            } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
                this.moveRight = false;
            }
        }

    });


    sg.Player = Player;

})();




/**********************************/


(function createGame() {

    var Game = Class.extend({

        canvas: null,
        context: null,
        width: null,
        height: null,

        init: function (width, height) {

            this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

            this.width = width || 800;
            this.height = height || 600;

            this.canvas.width = this.width;
            this.canvas.height = this.height;
        },

        clear: function () {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        },

        draw: function () {

            this.clear();       

            for (var i = 0; i < sg.entities.length; i++) {
                sg.entities[i].draw(this.context);
            }
        },

        update: function (elapsed) {

            for (var i = 0; i < sg.entities.length; i++) {
                sg.entities[i].update(elapsed);
            }
        },

        keyDown: function (e) {

            for (var i = 0; i < sg.entities.length; i++) {

                if (typeof sg.entities[i].keyDown === 'function') {
                    sg.entities[i].keyDown(e);
                }
            }
        },


        keyUp: function (e) {

            for (var i = 0; i < sg.entities.length; i++) {
                if (typeof sg.entities[i].keyUp === 'function') {
                    sg.entities[i].keyUp(e);
                }
            }
        }

    });

    sg.Game = Game;

    var game = sg.currentGame = new sg.Game(800, 600);


    var player = new sg.Player(200, 459);

    sg.createEntity(player);

    function update(elapsed) {

        game.update(elapsed);
    }

    var lastUpdate = Date.now();

    function draw() {

        var now = Date.now();
        var elapsed = (now - lastUpdate);
        lastUpdate = now;

        game.draw();
        update(elapsed);
        requestAnimFrame(draw);
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', sg.currentGame.keyDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', sg.currentGame.keyUp, false);

    draw();

})();
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling the memory in the Chrome debugger tools? I guess a runaway memory leak could trigger GC more often than you need.

Comment: Just to add, it's running absolutely fine for me on latest Chrome and Firefox (Windows 7)

Comment: I did a CPU profile a few days ago, but nothing stood out.  The memory profile doesn't stand out either.  It's typical of what I see in any other canvas game.  A rise in memory then GC hits.  From what I see the GC is only hitting every 30 seconds or so.  At least a big GC hit.  I'm just wondering if your not noticing because of GPU accelerated canvas on Windows.  I don't think current Chrome has that for MacOSX.  Maybe Canary does.

Comment: Yeah I profiled the first link and got no serious memory implications... Confusing! But as I say, works fine for me. You're doing all the right things - processing as little as possible in event handlers, scheduling animation with RequestAnimationFrame, etc.

Comment: Just doesn't make sense.  I can play canvas Angry Birds with no problems.  This is just simple movement and it's terrible.

Comment: Can you go to chrome://gpu/ and take a look? AFAIK hardware-acceleration is enabled for MacOSX as well.

Comment: Ok cool.  Thanks.  It is enabled.

Comment: Does OSX have an equivalent of the task manager? It might be related to your system memory usage itself.

Comment: Of course.  I have 4GB free.  Out of 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

The keydown/keyup events are waiting a little bit of time between one and another press.

Here is how I solved on my case (not sure if that's exactly your problem); adding a setInterval that every 20ms checks if there are key downs (more than one for diagonal movements).

```
    var keys = {};
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
        delete keys[e.which];
    });
    $(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
        keys[e.which] = true;
    });

    setInterval(keyEvent, 20);

    function keyEvent(){
        for(var idKeyPressed in keys){
            switch(idKeyPressed){
                case "87": // "W" key; Move to the top
                    // Do something
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Interesting theory about delays in the key events... But I can't see how this would solve it?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for your help but the issue occurs also with movement without key presses.